# Tron arcade game (Python, tkinter) - Collision detection

Tags: python, tkinter, collision, detection

I'm trying to program the Tron arcade game in Python with tkinter. 
I'm having some problems with collision detection. My problem is that I'm not sure how to keep track of the tails, the players is drawing where ever they move.
My first thought was to create a new list everytime I created a new rectangle. Then check these lists compared to the players location, each time they move. Though I'm not sure how I should write a loop, that will keep checking the new lists. 
Then i found out it was possible to add a list, to another list. So I thought I could make one list with all the coordinates of the rectangles in it, but it seems like it just overwrites the old coordinates when ever they move, instead of adding it to it, even though I use append.
I'm trying to do these things inside the function moving.

This is how my code looks at the moment, without any code from the previous attempts I just described. Please tell me if you need any other information.

```
#   Imports
from tkinter import*
import datetime
import math
from time import sleep
t = datetime.datetime.now

#   Variables
canvasHeight = 400
canvasWidth = 400

player1Spawn = 75, 200, 80, 205
player2Spawn = 325, 200, 320, 205

x1Move = 5
y1Move = 0
x2Move = -5
y2Move = 0

#   Window and canvas creation
window = Tk()
window.title("Tron")
canvas = Canvas(height = canvasHeight, width = canvasWidth)

canvas.pack()
canvas.focus_set()

#   Object creation
player1 = canvas.create_rectangle(player1Spawn, fill = "blue", outline = "blue")
player2 = canvas.create_rectangle(player2Spawn, fill = "red", outline = "red")

#   Movement and tail creation
def moving():
    global player1
    global player2
    global canvas
    p1Coords = canvas.coords(player1)
    p2Coords = canvas.coords(player2)
    p1CoordList = []
    p2CoordList = []
    p1CoordList.append(p1Coords)
    p2CoordList.append(p2Coords)
    canvas.create_rectangle(p1CoordList, fill = "blue", outline = "blue")
    canvas.create_rectangle(p2CoordList, fill = "red", outline = "red")
    del p1CoordList[0]
    del p2CoordList[0]
    canvas.move(player1, x1Move, y1Move)
    canvas.move(player2, x2Move, y2Move)
    window.after(50, moving)

def moveVar(event):
    global x1Move
    global y1Move
    global x2Move
    global y2Move

    if event.keysym == "Up":
        x1Move = 0
        y1Move = -5
    elif event.keysym == "Down":
        x1Move = 0
        y1Move = 5
    elif event.keysym == "Right":
        x1Move = 5
        y1Move = 0
    elif event.keysym == "Left":
        x1Move = -5
        y1Move = 0

    if event.keysym == "w":
        x2Move = 0
        y2Move = -5
    elif event.keysym == "s":
        x2Move = 0
        y2Move = 5
    elif event.keysym == "d":
        x2Move = 5
        y2Move = 0
   elif event.keysym == "a":
        x2Move = -5
        y2Move = 0

canvas.bind("<KeyPress>", moveVar)

moving()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
In particular, we should be able to post your given code into a file, run it, and reproduce the problem with no further input.  You need to provide a driver program and tracing print statements that illustrate the problem.

Comment: I have reasons to believe that your code isn't indented correctly, please fix them.

Comment: I can see I've missed one space character, gonna fix it now. If you noticed anything else than this one, please tell me what you're thinking of.

Comment: For example: your if statements are *not* in the function "moveVar", as displayed in the formatted question. Tip: an easy way to put in code and maintain proper indentation is to copy/paste, highlight the entire code, and click the `{}` button.

Comment: You are always setting `p1CoordList = []`, setting it back to empty, before adding the current coordinate.

Comment: Ajean, yeah I see now. I missed that. In my code it's in the function. Thanks for the tip, new to the website.
hcs, yeah that's intentional. So I dont keep creating rectangles in places I already have done it. Not exactly sure what our thoughts are.